# Is a no RSS plugin setup supposed to work?

Tags: rss

I'm using WP 3.1.2 as provided by Awardspace, a free hosting service. I haven't made any configuration regarding RSS but it seems to work on Google Reader. However, pictures and flash elements won't appear. Is this normal? Should I get a plugin then?

Thanks in advance - Victor.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included links to the site and feed.

Comment: it's vemv.net/blog, has no specific RSS link (I think) and the theme is Twenty Ten (tweaked gently).

Comment: When I subscribe to your feed via http://vemv.net/blog/feed I do see the images in your posts, see http://i.imgur.com/sHKM9.png

Comment: Weird, yesterday it didn't work, now it does. So there's no support for Flash?

Answer (score 1):

When you say pictures, you mean post thumbnails ?

If yes, then you can add them to your RSS feeds like this, add in functions.php

```
function rss_post_thumbnail( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . '</p>' . get_the_content();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
```

Comment: I guess that the two last lines have to be added somewhere else instead? Otherwise I get a Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter(). Or maybe the values you're providing are just examples...? Thanks

Comment: No, the whole piece of code should be placed into the `functions.php` file that is in your template directory.

Comment: It gives me the said error then... for some reason images display correctly now anyway so this wouln't be needed anymore.

Comment: By the way, isn't it really weird that WP can't display Flash elements?